# HashMap<String, String> text to TextView in Second Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, hashmap, textview

I have a `ListView` using a `HashMap<String, String>` that I wish to pass to a second activity.

On the second acivity I have some `TextView` and I need a `TextView` to set the text of the chosen item on the `HashMap`.

The problem is that instead of the key or value, ("Example1" or "Example2") I get this in the `TextView`:

> {First=Example1, Second=Example2    }

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    EditText buscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.busqueda);
    final TreeMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new TreeMap<>();

    nameAddresses.put   ("Example1", "Example2");



    final List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"First", "Second"},
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});

    Iterator it = nameAddresses.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First", pair.getKey().toString());
        resultsMap.put("Second", pair.getValue().toString());
        listItems.add(resultsMap);
    }


    resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    resultsListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);


    resultsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("Titulo", resultsListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Second Activity:

```
TextView mTextView;
TextView mTextView2;
TextView mTextView3;
TextView mTextView4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTitulo);
    mTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tSubtitulo);
    button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mTextView3.setText(bundle.getString("Titulo"));
```

Comment: *I get this ... {First=Example1, Second=Example2 } .toString()* ... becase that what you get with `toString()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should serialize your HashMap using JSON before you pass it to your second activity and reconstruct the data there. Android comes with support for this so you can use `org.json.JSONObject`. This means you can do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Titulo", new JSONObject(resultsListView.getItemAtPosition(position)).toString());

startActivity(intent);
```

And in your `SecondActivity` do:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    JSONObject myHashMap = JSONObject(bundle.getString("Titulo"));
    mTextView3.setText(myHashMap.optString('First', 'error'));
}
```

`myHashMap` is *not* a HashMap but you can use it in a similar manner. You read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#pubmethods).

Comment: `JSONObject myHashMap = bundle.getString("Titulo");` <= this will not even compile